# Mac OS X native printing from a Java desktop application

Tags: java, macos, printing

I would like to implement Mac OS X native printing in my Java desktop application.

That is, this print dialog when the user chooses to print:
[image]
<sub>(source: [blogcdn.com](https://www.blogcdn.com/www.tuaw.com/media/2008/09/terminal-tips_-make-extended-print-dialog-default.jpg))</sub>

which then expands to a dialog such as this:
[image]
As I understand it, native Mac OS X applications can customise the 2nd dialog by adding an option in the lower drop-down ("TextEdit" in the screenshot) which when selected displays options specific to the application.

How is the best way to go about achieving this in my Java application? I presume I will need to write some Objective C to do what I need, then use JNA/JNI to call it? Are they are pre-existing libraries that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in think you need to go down the JNI route.

Apple has a tech note on developing JNI routines here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2147/_index.html

Comment: Is this link still valid?